# how can a 1 second audio effect be played for 0.5 seconds in AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, avaudioplayer

I am using the following code to play sound effects in my Swift SpriteKit game.

```
    func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer  {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("NO AUDIO PLAYER")
    }

    return audioPlayer!
}
```

The sound effect duration is a second and I call it each time a sprite is created at a 0.5 second interval. Since the sound effect is longer than the creation interval, the effect only plays once. I believe reducing the effect duration could solve this issue, though I am open to other approaches to solving my problem.

Comment: if you need the song to be a second in other places, then my question is how do you want to play the sound,  super fast or only half the sound.  If the sound is only .5 second cut, then I would just go into iTunes and create a .5 second clip of it

Comment: I would prefer it to be played faster, within half a second

Comment: then I would recommend switching to using a SKNode child node with an SKAction,  and use SKAction.playSoundWithFileNamed to play your sound,  then run the speed at 2x (Unless of course this sound ALWAYS plays at 2x,  then I would pregenerate the 2x version and keep the node at 1x)  If this is the route you want to take,  I will make an answer explainging this

Comment: Try using SKAction.playSoundWithFileNamed every interval int needs to be played, and control the time interval in the update() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `AVAudioEngine()`

Just put your audioFile in `AVAudioEngine()` and change the speed with the following parameter:

```
// The default value is 1.0. The range of supported values is 1/32 to 32.0.
changeAudioUnitTime.rate = 1.0
```

**ExampleCode below:**

```
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    var audioFile: AVAudioFile!
    var audioPlayerNode: AVAudioPlayerNode?

    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: currentAudio!)
    audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: audioPlayer!.url!)
    audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode!)

    let changeAudioUnitTime = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
    // The default value is 1.0. The range of supported values is 1/32 to 32.0.
    changeAudioUnitTime.rate = 1.0
    audioEngine.attachNode(changeAudioUnitTime)
    audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode!, to: changeAudioUnitTime, format: nil)
    audioEngine.connect(changeAudioUnitTime, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)
            audioPlayerNode!.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
    do {
       try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
       print("audio Engine could not be started: \(error)")
    }

    // play the costumized sound
    audioPlayerNode!.play()
```

Hope this example helps you.... if I understood you wrong please feel free to correct me. Regards, Alex